# Flexible width and height of pre-rendered image using Shiny and renderImage()

Tags: shiny

I am calling a bunch of pre-rendered images into a Shiny app using renderImage(). I would like these png images to be in the sidebar and adjust in width and height depending on the browser or device type (e.g., Chrome, Android). Thus, I want the app to be mobile friendly. I can't figure out how to make it flexible like this (e.g., max-width = 500px or width = 100% like you would do in other languages).

A simple example:

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("title panel"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel( "sidebar panel",
                  sliderInput("route", label = "Route Number:",
                              min = 1, max = 5, value = 1),
                  imageOutput("Image")),
    mainPanel("main panel")
  )
))
```

and server.R:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$Image <- renderImage({
    filename <- normalizePath(file.path('www/maps',
                                        paste(input$route, '.png', sep='')))
        list(src = filename,
         alt = paste("Image number", input$route))

  }, deleteFile = FALSE)
})
```

Cheers,

Caitlin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out myself. As far as I know, there is no way to handle this in R. Instead, use your style sheet (e.g., bootstrap.css) by adding something like this:

```
   img {
      border: 1;
      max-width: 100%;
    }
    element.style {
      width: 33.33%;
    }
```

I was also successful in getting this to work with a leaflet map in Shiny. This is what I did in my style sheet:

```
div#myChart2 {
  width: inherit;
}
```

Comment: `@cnmillar` could explain how to link the css file with the shiny app?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem but it is possible to handle the problem inside Shiny.
Here is what I did:

```
     output$photokib <- renderImage({
  ak <- formatC(ak, width = 4, format = "d", flag = "0")
  photo <- normalizePath(file.path('Data/photos',
                                         paste(image,'_1','.jpg', sep='' )))
  list(src = photo,
       width = 400,
       height = 300)
},deleteFile = FALSE)
```

Comment: So you basically set the width and the height. That works. Can you please explain what are you doing with the formatC() part?