# Neatly display images of different sizes sequentially in the same UI element

Tags: css, r, shiny

In my app, I need to display a single pre-rendered image amongst other UI elements.  I'd like the other elements to wrap tightly around the top and bottom of image.  The image displayed depends on the state of the app, and the images may be of different sizes.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29179088/flexible-width-and-height-of-pre-rendered-image-using-shiny-and-renderimage) addresses a similar problem, but seems to differ in that many images of different sizes need to be displayed simmultaneously.

Here is a MWE displaying the problem.  You can either supply your own images, or download them along with the rest of my RStudio project [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7llbcq0r9jz41za/dynamicImageResize.zip?dl=0).

```
library(shiny)
library(png)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$link(rel="stylesheet", type="text/css", href="stylesheet.css")),
  selectInput("size", label="Size:", choices=c("small", "large")),
  imageOutput("image"),
  # uiOutput("imageUI"),
  textOutput("info")
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
  imgFileName <- reactive({
    paste0("./www/", input$size, ".png")
  })
  
  imgFile <- reactive({
    readPNG(imgFileName(), info=TRUE)
  })
  
  imgSize <- reactive({
    info <- unlist(stringr::str_split(attr(imgFile(), "info")$dim, stringr::fixed(" ")))
    info <- paste0(info, "px")
    names(info) <- c("width", "height")
    info <- as.list(info)
    info
  })
  
  output$info <- renderText({
    paste0("Height: ", imgSize()$height, "; Width: ", imgSize()$width)
  })
  
  output$image <- renderImage({
    list(
       src=imgFileName(),
       contentType="image/png",
       width=imgSize()$width,
       height=imgSize()$height,
       alt=paste0("A ", input$size, " image"),
       class="myImageClass"
    )
  })

  # output$imageUI <- renderUI({
  #   tagList(plotOutput("image"))
  # })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

If you run the MWE, you'll see that there is a large gap between the image and the text output when the value of the select input is `small` and the image overlaps the text output when the select input is `large`.

These screenshots display the desired behaviour.

[image: Desired behaviour]

Examining the underlying HTML (in Firefox, right click anywhere on the image and select "Inspect Element"), the problem appears to be caused by the `div` that wraps the image:

[image: Element Inspector]

The `img` has picked up the image's size correctly, but the surrounding elements are being held in place by the inline `height` attribute of the surrounding `div`.  To demonstrate that this is the problem, I can disable the offending height attribute in Firefox's inspector:

[image: Editing the div]

and this gives me the desired behaviour.

If the problem was caused by one of the CSS classes referenced in the `div`, I could probably solve the problem by overwriting the class definition in the app's stylesheet.  But the offending attribute is inline, so that's not an option.

How can I modify the attributes of the `div` that wraps the `img` that displays the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were really close with `uiOutput()` which is necessary because you want the layout of the UI to change. Whereas what you have uncommented only swaps the images in and out but keeps the UI layout constant.

```
library(shiny)
library(png)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$link(rel="stylesheet", type="text/css", href="stylesheet.css")),
  selectInput("size", label="Size:", choices=c("small", "large")),
  
  # don't use imageOutput() here because the UI will not be able to change
  #imageOutput("image"),
  # instead use uiOutput() which will allow you to update the UI itself
  # that is, you will be able to update the height of the image div reactively
  uiOutput("imageUI"),
  textOutput("info")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  imgFileName <- reactive({
    paste0("./www/", input$size, ".png")
  })
  
  imgFile <- reactive({
    readPNG(imgFileName(), info=TRUE)
  })
  
  imgSize <- reactive({
    info <- unlist(stringr::str_split(attr(imgFile(), "info")$dim, stringr::fixed(" ")))
    info <- paste0(info, "px")
    names(info) <- c("width", "height")
    info <- as.list(info)
    info
  })
  
  output$info <- renderText({
    paste0("Height: ", imgSize()$height, "; Width: ", imgSize()$width)
  })
  
  output$image <- renderImage({
    list(
       src=imgFileName(),
       contentType="image/png",
       width=imgSize()$width,
       height=imgSize()$height,
       alt=paste0("A ", input$size, " image"),
       class="myImageClass"
    )
  })

  # update the UI here by changing the height of the image div
  output$imageUI <- renderUI({
    imageOutput("image", height = imgSize()$height)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: That's great.  Thank you.  As you surmised, I'd tried various things with `renderUI`, but the solution was obviously one that I missed.  This is exactly what I wanted.