# If a value change in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I seek a method in R shiny that I can include inside a `render` or an `observe` to check if a certain value has changed.

For example :

```R
library(shiny)
library(shinycssloaders)
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  fluidRow(
  column(5, 
    imageOutput("image") %>% withSpinner()
  ),
  actionButton("button", "redo")
  
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  data = reactiveVal(data.frame(
    gp = factor(rep(letters[1:3], each = 10)),
    y = rnorm(30)
  ))
  
  getWidth = function(image)
    paste0(session$clientData[[paste0("output_", image, "_width")]], "px")
  
  
  output$image = renderImage({
    input$button

    outfile = tempfile(fileext = ".png")
    p = ggplot(data(), aes(gp, y)) +
      geom_point()
    Sys.sleep(2) # to symbolise a plot which is very slow to appear

    ggsave(filename = outfile, p)
    
    
    return(list(src = outfile, width = getWidth("image")))
    
  }, deleteFile = F)
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Here just when I resize the window, the image is resaved, I do not want that. But I want that code to save the file if and only if `data()` or `input$button` is changed.

The only solution I see so far is to copy the data in an independent variable and to check if the value has changed. If the data change, save the new plot, change the value of the independent variable.

But I am not convinced that is it a good solution because the value data will be copied twice. For this dataset it not very severe, but for a dataset with millions lines the strain is harder. Or a graph that takes more than 10 seconds to save.

Thank you,

Comment: Make the image with a `reactiveValue`.  (Or combine it with `data` in a `reactiveValues` object.  Then use `renderUI` rather than `renderImage` to display the plot.  The answer to [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66015301/neatly-display-images-of-different-sizes-sequentially-in-the-same-ui-element) here demonstrates the required technique.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be

- Use renderPlot instead of renderImage
- Create the plot in a reactive expression
- Save only when the plot changes (now it only reacts to data changes not to resizes) or the button is pressed, by using an observeEvent with those two events as triggers.

Find a working example below. If you want to change the size of the saved plot do it in the ggsave.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinycssloaders)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  fluidRow(
    column(5, 
           imageOutput("image") %>% withSpinner()
    ),
    actionButton("button", "redo")
    
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  data = reactiveVal(data.frame(
    gp = factor(rep(letters[1:3], each = 10)),
    y = rnorm(30)
  ))
  
  p <- reactive({ggplot(data(), aes(gp, y)) +
      geom_point()
    })
  
  observeEvent(c(p(), input$button), {
    outfile = tempfile(fileext = ".png")
    ggsave(filename = outfile, p())
  })
  
  
  output$image = renderPlot({
    Sys.sleep(2) # to symbolise a plot which is very slow to appear
    p()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: But it would be better if the R shiny developers would implement a fonction like `isChanged` in there package.