# Image fit to box element - R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I'm try to plot my image to box element in r shiny. But I get problem about the image size that can't dynamically change follow the box element size. I have tried to set height and width of image, but the problem is not resolved. This is my code:

```
ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    column(8, box(title=NULL, width=12, imageOutput('my_image')))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$my_image <- renderImage({
    filename <- normalizePath(file.path('.','image.jpg'))
    
    list(src = filename, height = 'auto', width = 'auto',
         contentType = 'image/jpg')
    
    }, deleteFile = F)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

what should I do? I don't have a good basic html and javascript.

Comment: So you don't know the size of your image until you load the image file, right?  That means the UI has already been created, so it's too late to adjust the size of the surrounding `div`.  I had a similar problem, and it was solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66015301/neatly-display-images-of-different-sizes-sequentially-in-the-same-ui-element).