# Excessive whitespace between rows: Interaction between nested fluidRow and renderImage

Tags: r, image, shiny, shinydashboard

I am new to Shiny and Shinydashboard for R and have run into a tricky issue. I am using nested fluidRow() and get excessive whitespace between rows ***if*** a column in the nested fluidRow includes an imageOutput() element. This has nothing to do with margins (which stackoverflow has several posts related to).

Here is a screenshot of how it looks:
[Shiny Dashboard page with two boxes. The top one with an image. The two boxes/rows have an excessive space between them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/haN3l.png)

Here is (my first) reprex:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

setwd("E:/Dokumenter/R workspace")

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Header"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(id = "sidebar",
      menuItem(
        "Page with two fluid rows",
        tabName = "TabOne",
        icon = icon("question")
      )
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "TabOne",
        fluidRow(
          column(width=12,
            box(
              title = "Row 1",
              width = NULL,
              height= 150,
              solidHeader = TRUE,
              status="primary",
              fluidRow( # In my full code I have multiple columns here
                 column(width=12,
                    "Text 1",
                    imageOutput("image") # The excessive space disappears if this line is commented out
                 )
              )
            ) # box
          ),
          column(width=12,
            box(
              title = "Row 2",
              solidHeader = TRUE,
              status="primary",
              "Text 2"
            )
          )
        ) # fluidrow
      ) # tabitem
      ) #tabitems
    ) # DashboardBody
) # DashboardPage

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
    output$image <- renderImage({
    ImgTxt <- "image1.jpg" # Image size does not change the output behaviour
    width <- 50
    list(src = ImgTxt,
         contentType = "image/jpg",
         width = width,
         height = "auto"
    )
  }, deleteFile = FALSE)


}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Commenting out the line with the image fixes the issue, but I want the image. Note that the nested fluidRow only has one column in this reprex and isn't really needed, but in my full code, I have more columns. The image size does not change the size of the gap, neither does the height/width settings of the renderImage() function or specifying both instead of using "auto".

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66015301/neatly-display-images-of-different-sizes-sequentially-in-the-same-ui-element) will help solve your problem.

Comment: @Limey It did! Thanks! Using uiOutput() instead of imageOutput in "ui" and wrapping imageOutput within a renderUI() in "server" as your link described fixed the problem. I am unsure how I can mark your comment as an answer? And whether I should include the solution in full?

Comment: I'll mark your question as a duplicate.  Not a criticism of you, just a helpful hint for other searchers.  I'm happy to have helped.